# Does Windows 8 sdk support printing?

Tags: printing, windows-8, sdk

I want to make an app for windows 8, this app should have a built-in print functionality.
I know that Ios sdk support printing for AirPrint-capable printers, how about Windows 8 SDK?

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Store apps?

Comment: Definitely need to provide more context, here. You mention iOS SDK, so I'm guessing you mean for Windows 8 Phone? More specifics, please!

Comment: Yes I mean Windows store  Apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Windows store apps do support printing, here're the links to API, quick start and guidelines for starters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448418(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868178.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780609.aspx